# What is meant by "scale family of densities"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, inference

I was wondering what the exact definition of this is. Apparently the exponential distribution is an example of such a family of densities. But what is the precise definition of a scale family? Also, I've heard of location and location-scale families in the same context and I'm not sure what these are either.

Answer (score 6):

Definition 3.5.4 from [Casella & Berger](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Statistical_Inference.html?id=0x_vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Let $f(x)$ be any pdf. Then for any $\sigma >0$, the family of pdfs $(1/\sigma) f(x/\sigma)$, indexed by the parameter $\sigma$, is called the scale family with standard pdf $f(x)$ and $\sigma$ is called the scale parameter of the family.

Comment: +1.  I am surprised, though, that C&B chose such a narrow definition.  We could let $F$ be any distribution, continuous or not, and define the associated scale family as the set of distributions given by $F(x/\sigma), \sigma\gt 0$.